# Create a versatile Venn diagram with color blending

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

On https://texample.net/tikz/examples/venn/, there is an example for a Venn diagram with color blending:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]
    \fill[red!30!white]   ( 90:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[green!30!white] (210:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[blue!30!white]  (330:1.2) circle (2);
  \end{scope}
  \node at ( 90:2)    {Typography};
  \node at ( 210:2)   {Design};
  \node at ( 330:2)   {Coding};
  \node [font=\Large] {\LaTeX};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code seems to be a bit redundant and not that flexible.

- The background circles are drawn independent of the actual nodes.
- The position is set with polar coordinates explicitly, which means that manual mistakes can happen and one needs to change things in many places in case one wants to add a circle.

Can this be further improved (for example, by only relying on nodes – tried that, but blending will also have an effect on the font, unfortunately)? Can the position, size etc. of the circles be set in a better way?

Comment: You can use relative positioning by including `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` and replacing polar coordinates. See the manual for details.

Comment: It is already made in a smart way. `positioning` is for rectangular positioning and not  polar positioning. The labels are placed along the direction but not in the center of the circles. Exactly what figure(placement of nodes and labels) do you wish to create?

Comment: Currently, I plan to create a figure similar to the one in the template, but with four, not three circles. Also, I ideally want to have a general solution that can also work with three of five circles for example without needing too much manual interactions (apart from adding notes).

Comment: That‘s quite limited in variation, so preparing two examples will be enough. Unfortunately tikz doesn‘t always seem to cooperate with \newcommand. So instead I suggest the following: define color by style, see pgf manual; use \newcommand to define and expand node-texts. // Or generate tikz code by some generator, i.e. scripting. However, that max be overdone for this task.

Comment: I was hoping, TikZ offers some nice functionality to do this. For example, I don't really like the current separation of circles and nodes.